# mongodb database name is "TEST" with typeorm nest setup

Tags: mongodb, typeorm, nest, nestjs-typeorm

I am on my typescript backend api project with nest, I am trying to configure my database with typeorm, with the following configuration: the problem being that it creates the database for me but it has the name "test" and name not "prosperity" which I specify in my .env file

It's as if he doesn't know the name I give him.

```
export function ormConfig(): any {
  return {
    type: 'mongodb',
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    dbName: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    connectTimeout: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT),
    acquireTimeout: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_ACQUIRE_TIME_OUT),
    extra: {
      connectionLimit: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_LIMIT),
    },
    entities: ['dist/**/entity/*.entity.js'],
    migrations: ['dist/database/migrations/*.js'],
    subscribers: ['dist/observers/subscribers/*.subscriber.js'],
    cli: {
      entitiesDir: 'src/components/**/entity',
      migrationsDir: 'src/database/migrations',
      subscribersDir: 'src/observers/subscribers',
    },
  };
}
```

```
NODE_ENV=development
SERVER_TIMEOUT=1080000
SERVER_PORT=3101

DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=27017
DATABASE_USERNAME=admin
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_NAME=prosperity
DATABASE_TYPE=mongodb
DATABASE_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT=150000
DATABASE_ACQUIRE_TIME_OUT=150000
DATABASE_CONNECTION_LIMIT=20
```

On the other hand, if I put "admin" as the base name and it already exists, it finds it and creates the associated collections there.

I know that the field we should put is not "dbName" but rather "database", Except that if I put "database", I get these errors:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0iyE.png)

"[Nest] 13236  - 26/10/2023 21:41:37   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)..."

here is my appModule

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormConfig()),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

can you help me ? THANKS

I tried to put the minimum possible property in configuration typeorm, but it still doesn't work, database name is "Test". I just want it to generate my database with the right name